# Getting objects in an array to count to 10

Tags: java, multithreading, count, counter

I am trying to get student objects in an array to count to 10, I have created a getCounter() method which counts from 0 - 9, but I want each of the student objects to count from 1 - 10. So for example the outcome that I am expecting is:

```
MathStudent[1] - John: Count:1 
MathStudent[2] - Marcus: Count: 1 
...
ComputerStudent[3] - Alberto: Count: 1 
... 
Upto the point that all reach Count: 10
```

Also I have created the array in a thread class so it should sleep for 1 second in between the counts.

Below is the code I have in thread class:

```
public class StudentThread extends Thread {

    public void run(){
       Student s[] = new Student[10];


        s[0] = new MathStudent("Smith");
        s[1] = new MathStudent("Jack");
        s[2] = new MathStudent("Victor");
        s[3] = new MathStudent("Mike");
        s[4] = new ScienceStudent("Dave");
        s[5] = new ScienceStudent("Oscar");
        s[6] = new ScienceStudent("Peter");
        s[7] = new ComputerStudent("Philip");
        s[8] = new ComputerStudent("Shaun");
        s[9] = new ComputerStudent("Scott");

        for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
            System.out.print(loop);
            System.out.println(s[loop].getSubjects());
            s[loop].getCounter();
        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**
I have updated the code and managed to get an output which is similar to what i want but its not there yet, please tell me what i doing wrong.

Main class:

```
public class JavaLab5 {
    public static final int DEBUG = 0;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentThread studentThread = new StudentThread();
        studentThread.start();


    }

}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {
    static int  studentCounter;
    String name;
    int count = 0;
    public static int instances = 0;

    // Getters
    public  String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        if (JavaLab5.DEBUG > 3) System.out.println("In Student.setName. Name = "+ name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates name,age and gender 
     * with defaults
     */
    public Student() {
        instances++;
        this.name = "Not Set";
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param name String with the name
    */
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Destructor
     * @throws Throwable 
     */
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        //do finalization here
        instances--;
        super.finalize(); //not necessary if extending Object.
    } 

    /**
     *
     */
    public void getCounter() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return this.name; 
    }

    public String getSubjects() {
      return this.getSubjects();
    }


}
```

ComputerStudent class:

```
public class ComputerStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;


    /**
     * Default constructor
     * @fortanGrade
     * @adaGrade
     */
    public ComputerStudent() {
        super();
    }

    public ComputerStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studentCounter++;
        studCountObj=studentCounter;

    }


    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Computer Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "] " + name + ": "); 
    }
}
```

MathStudent class:

```
public class MathStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     * @param name
     */
    public MathStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    public MathStudent() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" MathStudent" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": ");
    }
}
```

ScienceStudent class:

```
public class ScienceStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;
    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ScienceStudent() {
        super();
    }

    public ScienceStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studentCounter++;
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
     @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Science Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": " + "Count: ");
    } 
}
```

StudentThread class:
public class StudentThread extends Thread {

```
public void run(){
   Student s[] = new Student[11];


    s[0] = new MathStudent("Smith");
    s[1] = new MathStudent("Jack");
    s[2] = new MathStudent("Victor");
    s[3] = new MathStudent("Mike");
    s[4] = new ScienceStudent("Dave");
    s[5] = new ScienceStudent("Oscar");
    s[6] = new ScienceStudent("Peter");
    s[7] = new ComputerStudent("Philip");
    s[8] = new ComputerStudent("Shaun");
    s[9] = new ComputerStudent("Scott");


    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
       for (Student item : s) {
           System.out.print(item.getSubjects() + " - " + "Count:");
           item.getCounter();
           //System.out.println(s[loop].getSubjects());
       }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        }
    }

    //}
    //for (int loop = 0; loop < s.length; loop++) {
        //s[0].getCounter();
    //}
}
```

}

This is the output I get:

```
MathStudent[0]-Smith:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
 MathStudent[1]-Jack:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
 MathStudent[2]-Victor:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
 MathStudent[3]-Mike:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
7
8
9
10
 Science Student[5]-Dave: Count:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
 Science Student[6]-Oscar: Count:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
 Science Student[7]-Peter: Count:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:1
2
3
    at javalab5.StudentThread.run(StudentThread.java:32)
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The output counts each student once instead of counting until it reaches count 10. Also the student number skips 4 and goes straight to 5 which I don't understand why.

Comment: `System.out.print(loop+1);` ?

Comment: Do you want each students to count in their own thread?

Comment: @Yohannes no not in their own thread, all students should count in the same thread.

Comment: in your output : why are all Count :1. please clarify what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Yohannes First all the students should count: 1, then count:2 etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. You want to count each student 10 times? Because that seems like what you're going for here, which seems pointless without a context.

Comment: It always seems crazy when people have multiple threads but they want the output to be in a specific order.  The whole _point_ of threads is that they run asynchronously.  You might as well do this in a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe the current output of running your existing code?  I think it might be as simple as a missing increment for Students in indexes 1 through 9.

Your second for loop is not using the loop variable in the array access:

```
for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
    s[0].getCounter();
}
```

should be:

```
for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
    s[loop].getCounter();
}
```

You don't really need two loops to do this.  You can do the s[loop].getCounter(); as the last line in the first for loop.

Comment: see the updated post which shows the output I get after doing what you said.

Answer (score 0):

> I want each of the student objects to count from 1 - 10.

The you need two *nested* loops.

The inner loop iterates over the students in the array, the outer loop defines how far the students count:

```
for(int currentCount = 0; currentCount<10 ; currentCount++){ // ten times
   for(Student student: s){ // each student
     student.getCounter();
   }
}
```

> Also I have created the array in a thread class so it should sleep for 1 second in between the counts.

This was wrong. Threads are needed to do some work *in parallel*, but you want a *pause*.

On the other hand: the method `sleep()` which lets your program pause is available in class Thread. But you can access it without extending Thread:

```
for(int currentCount = 0; currentCount<10 ; currentCount++){ // ten times
   for(Student student: s){ // each student
     student.getCounter();
     Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep 1000 ms -> 1s
   }
}
```

Comment: When I try this it gives me the following output: `0 Math Student - Smith: 
0
1 Math Student - Jack: 
0
2 Math Student - Victor: 
0
3 Math Student - Mike: 
0
4 Science Student - Dave: Count: 
0
5 Science Student - Oscar: Count: 
0
6 Science Student - Peter: Count: 
0
7 Computer Student - Philip: 
0
8 Computer Student - Shaun: 
0
9 Computer Student - Scott: 
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1`

Comment: which is not exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will generate your expected output :

```
public class TestClass {

      public  void run(){
         // int studentCounter;
        Student[] s = new Student[10];

             s[0] = new MathStudent("Smith");
            s[1] = new MathStudent("Jack");
            s[2] = new MathStudent("Victor");
            s[3] = new MathStudent("Mike");
            s[4] = new ScienceStudent("Dave");
            s[5] = new ScienceStudent("Oscar");
            s[6] = new ScienceStudent("Peter");
            s[7] = new ComputerStudent("Philip");
            s[8] = new ComputerStudent("Shaun");
            s[9] = new ComputerStudent("Scott");

        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

                System.out.println(s[i].toString() + " - "
                        + s[i].getStudentName() + "Count :" + j);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}


class Student {
    static int  studentCounter;
    String studentName;

    public Student() {

    }
public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}
}

class MathStudent extends Student {

     int studCountObj;
    public MathStudent(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        studentCounter++;
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "MathStudent"  + "[" +studCountObj+ "]";

    }

}

class ComputerStudent extends Student {
     int studCountObj;

    public ComputerStudent(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        studentCounter++;
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "ComputerStudent"  + "[" +studCountObj +"]";

    }



}

class ScienceStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;
    public ScienceStudent(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        studentCounter++;
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "ScienceStudent"  + "[" +studCountObj+ "]";

    }

}
```

Comment: How would I make it sleep for 1 second?

Comment: add a Thread.sleep() where every you want to sleep. where do you want to sleep and for how long?

Comment: I have added 1 second sleep . Next time make sure you add your own efforts also, and don't forget to accept it

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Im trying to use the getCounter() method in the Student class.

Comment: You can still tweak the code to use getCounter() if you wish to do so. What you have got so far is more than needed. Don't expect people to work your entire homework.